# How to extract str value in float Series of Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm handling huge data series which are consist of `float` values and Pandas.Series type.

I executed following code in Python.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read the specific column from CSV file.
float_log_series = pd.read_csv('./data.csv', usecols=['float_log']).float_log
data_cut = pd.cut(float_log_series, 20)
```

However, I got following error.

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

This error mentions that the data series could include `str` type data.

I would like to extract and remove this data.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Did you try `float_log_series.astype(float)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric` with option `errors='coerce'` and `dropna`

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 1, 3.4, 'c', 0, 2.0])

Out[24]:
0      a
1      1
2    3.4
3      c
4      0
5      2
dtype: object

s_out = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').dropna()

Out[29]:
1    1.0
2    3.4
4    0.0
5    2.0
dtype: float64
```